# passing a template class as arg parameter to std::bind

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do the following:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class G>
class Chain
{
 //....................some irrelevant code...............
 std::function<void (Node<T, G>&)> method_ptr;

 template<typename M>
 void SetMethodPointer(M* m, void(M::*ptr)(Node<T, G>&))
 {
      method_ptr(std::bind(ptr, m, std::placeholders::_1));
 }
```

where

```
G<T>
```

is some template class, and

```
Node<T, G>
```

is another template class which takes G as a template parameter.
Note that this template design by itself is OK and I had no issues with it as long as I was using simple function pointers; however, this time I needed to take a pointer to another class method inside the Chain template class.

Now the compiler (VS 2010) states the following error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::tr1::_Function_impl1<_Ret,_Arg0>::operator ()(_Arg0) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::tr1::_Bind<_Result_type,_Ret,_BindN>' to 'Node<T,G> '.
```

My question, is this related to some issue of passing the template class Node as an arg parameter to std::bind function? Either way, how can I rectify this error, if possible?

Thank you guys.

Comment: How about a nice [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: shouldn't it be `method_ptr = std::bind(ptr, m, std::placeholders::_1);`

Comment: `method_ptr = std::bind(...);`, you're trying to call `method_ptr`.

Comment: absolutely right, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
method_ptr(std::bind(ptr, m, std::placeholders::_1));
```

is a call to a function called `method_ptr` which accepts a function as argument. However `method_ptr` is declared to accept `Node<T, G>&`.

What you want to do is probably this (guessing from the name *SetMethodPointer*)

```
method_ptr = std::bind(ptr, m, std::placeholders::_1);
```